# What are the differences between using `rails server` and `rackup`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, thin, webrick

The only difference I've noted is that `rails server` starts the server on port 3000, while `rackup` starts the server on port 9292.

Are there any other differences?

Are there use cases for one instead of the other?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`rails server` is the command for starting your server (usually WEBrick) and is in [rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/commands.rb#L43).

`rackup` is a command that comes with the [rack](https://github.com/rack/rack/wiki/%28tutorial%29-rackup-howto) middle and uses the settings in your config.ru and starts a server based off of those.  This is a standard (it will work for other frameworks and rack-based applications) and is usually used in production servers.

One difference of note is that if you start a server with `rails s` then you will see the output in the terminal.

In my experience, in production, `rackup` is used by [phusion passenger](http://www.modrails.com/) so you wouldn't want `rails s` in that situation.

As an aside, the port can be changed with both `rails server` and `rackup` using the -p flag.